# CSS/HTML element formatting template

Tags: html, css, template

I'm trying to locate an HTML template that shows all the elements in HTML, so that the basic aspects of typography, colour schemes, margins and so on can be applied to it using CSS. Those styles can then be merged with styles that handle the layout for a given project, and then tweaked a little for any given problem.

I realize I could do this myself but thought that someone else may have already done this or know where to find such a template.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am looking for the exact same thing. I know I have seem something like this before somewhere. This template would allow us to practice on a style sheet and see how it effects every html element individually. There has to be something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BluePrint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/) might work for you. Updated in 2011.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are building a site that will look like other websites, creating a site off of an HTML template isn't a good idea. Maybe you could give a short description of what you want your website to look like in the end. That could give us a better vision of what you're trying to accomplish.

The reason is because CSS is dependent on other factors of your website. The specific widths and element placements within the HTML document will change the necessary CSS.

Try creating a purely graphical template of your site in Photoshop or Gimp. That way you can look at where you want different elements to go, put it into HTML and use CSS to style it accordingly.

There are plenty of CSS templates on the web that have different formatting of the basic website designs.